# How to Print Vertex Structure in a Loop

Tags: c++, data-structures, directx-11

I'm looking to print the content of my Vertex Buffer. I'd like to loop through all the vertices and texture coordinates while printing to a console. Specifically I'd like to see both vertex location and texels (texture coordinates). How would this be accomplished in a loop?

```
//vertex structure
struct Vertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT2 Tex;
};

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
pContext->Map(buff, NULL, D3D11_MAP_READ, NULL, &ms); 
Vertex* vertices = new Vertex[ms.DepthPitch];     
memcpy(vertices, ms.pData, ms.DepthPitch); 
pContext->Unmap(buff, 0);

//I know how to write a basic for loop,
//But I don't know how to query only pos or tex? 
for (int i = 0; i < 2678; i++) {
  cout << vertices[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: A) Why not `std:vector` here to store the data? B) Where's the loop? Start with `for` and go from there.

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop?

Comment: `memcpy(vertices, ms.pData, ms.DepthPitch);` -- The `memcpy` function works with bytes, not the number of items.  Unless you really meant to do this, this should be `memcpy(vertices, ms.pData, ms.DepthPitch * sizeof(Vertex));`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, According to D3D11 docs: DepthPitch returns "The depth pitch, or width, or physical size (in bytes)of the data." Given this info, does it still need sizeof()?

Comment: @lazylama -- Sorry, but you should determine this.  The `memcpy` function works with bytes, not number of objects in the array.  `memcpy` knows nothing about the type you are copying the data to, that's why it works strictly with a raw byte count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways the code above can fail, so it's important to include the error-handling.

Also `D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE` does not report the *size* of the vertex buffer in bytes through any of it's values, so you need to get it from `D3D11_BUFFER_DESC`  via `GetDesc`.

> `DepthPitch` is only a valid value if you are mapping a volume (3D) texture.

You are also assuming the vertex buffer itself is something you can directly `Map` either because you created it with `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` or `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` and you used `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_FLAG`.

```
//vertex structure
struct Vertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT2 Tex;
};

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms = {};
if (FAILED(pContext->Map(buff, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &ms)))
{
   cout << "Failed Map" << endl;
}
else
{
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc = {};
    buff->GetDesc(&desc);

    size_t nVerts = desc.ByteWidth / sizeof(Vertex);
    if (!nVerts)
    {
        cout << "Failed computing nVerts" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        auto vertices = new Vertex[nVerts];     
        memcpy(vertices, ms.pData, nVerts * sizeof(Vertex)); 
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nVerts; i++)
        {
            cout << vertices[i].Pos.x << ", "
                 << vertices[i].Pos.y << ", "
                 << vertices[i].Pos.z << endl;
        }
        delete [] vertices;
    }

    pContext->Unmap(buff, 0);
}
```

> Note a better way to handle the temporary `vertices` memory is to use  `auto vertices = std::make_unique<Vertex[]>(nVerts);` and add `#include <memory>` to the top. This avoids the need to remember to manually delete the memory in all cases.

> You should *also* be using [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/comptr-class) instead of raw COM interface pointers to avoid memory leaks with DirectX COM objects.

See also [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)